# How and when are the esm5 and esm2015 directories of a "ng build"-generated lib folder used?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, node-modules

In the folder generated by `ng build simple-lib`, I see a more complex structure than my other node modules. Instead of an index.js exporting and importing other members, I see a `bundles`, `esm2015`, `esm5`, and `public_api.d.ts`.

I see the compiled versions of simple-lib in both the esm5 and esm2015 folders. I'm wondering how the esm .js files are used and when esm2015 would be used instead of esm5. From what I understand, esm2015 allows for smaller bundles and tree-shaking, but I'm not sure when the choice is made about which module to use. I'm hoping to generate a lib that I can use in a node project and any help to understand if and how that would be possible would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$ tree simple-lib/
simple-lib/
├── bundles
│   ├── simple-lib.umd.js
│   ├── simple-lib.umd.js.map
│   ├── simple-lib.umd.min.js
│   └── simple-lib.umd.min.js.map
├── esm2015
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── simple-lib.component.js
│   │   ├── simple-lib.module.js
│   │   └── simple-lib.service.js
│   ├── public_api.js
│   └── simple-lib.js
├── esm5
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── simple-lib.component.js
│   │   ├── simple-lib.module.js
│   │   └── simple-lib.service.js
│   ├── public_api.js
│   └── simple-lib.js
├── fesm2015
│   ├── simple-lib.js
│   └── simple-lib.js.map
├── fesm5
│   ├── simple-lib.js
│   └── simple-lib.js.map
├── lib
│   ├── simple-lib.component.d.ts
│   ├── simple-lib.module.d.ts
│   └── simple-lib.service.d.ts
├── package.json
├── public_api.d.ts
├── simple-lib.d.ts
└── simple-lib.metadata.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While updating my angular version, I think I may have found the answer. The library that will be used is dependent on the browser requesting the application - ***The esm5 build will be used for older browsers that require more polyfills and the esm2015 libraries will be used for newer browsers that require fewer polyfills***

"The CLI's build command now automatically creates a modern ES2015 build with minimal polyfills and a compatible ES5 build for older browsers, and loads the appropriate file based on the browser. You may opt-out of this change by setting your target back to es5 in your tsconfig.json. Learn more on angular.io."

From https://update.angular.io/#7.1:9.0

Answer (score 1):

As per the "Angular Package Format" specs -

> In today’s JavaScript landscape, developers will consume packages in
>   many different ways. For example, some may use SystemJS, others could
>   use Webpack. Still, others might consume packages in Node or maybe in
>   the browser as a UMD bundle or through global variable access.

Read more from this link - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview